# How to setup Perfect Privacy VPN

Tags: vpn

What is the best way to setup Perfect Privacy VPN on Windows Phone? There is no Tutorial on https://www.perfect-privacy.com/german/anleitungen/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Settings. Select VPN. Turn on the VPN status. Select + to add/create a new profile.
2. server name: Enter DNS Name from https://www.perfect-privacy.com/german/member/server/
3. type: L2TP with IPSec
4. connect using: user name+password+preshared key
5. user name: your vpn account
6. password: your vpn password
7. preshared key: Enter IPSec PSK from https://www.perfect-privacy.com/german/member/server/